# Linking an image to open a youtube video in lightbox/fancybox in wordpress

Tags: plugins, videos

Here is what i'm having problems with... I want to link a youtube video to start playing in a lightbox/fancybox when a person clicks an image. Kind of like this site has - http://www.adroll.com/ - if you click the "Click to Play" (which is an image) a window will open (although not lightbox/fancybox) and video will start autoplaying.

Would preferably want to do it with the least possible programing needed. I can do some basic editing but don't really know how to write any PHP/javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow Tip #4: http://fancybox.net/blog.  or

I use [Easy FancyBox](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easy-fancybox/) for my wordpress sites. In the WP Admin, under Settings > Media you can edit the settings for Fancybox and it has a way to autodetect Youtube embeds.

Comment: Awesome, the plugin makes it super-easy :) Thanks for that